# How to change sprite width and cause more texture repetition?

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I have sprite with repeated texture and I want to change width frequently of sprite but on that way that cause texture to be repeated more times instead of stay same number of scaled repetition.
This is what happened when I change width with

```
setScaleX(factor) ;
```

I also tried to `getContentSize()` and change width and `setContentSize(newContentSize);` 
but it didn't help, just cause strange behaviour. How to change sprite width and cause more texture repetition ? Is this possible at all ?
( I can remove current sprite and recreate new but it looks like btute force solution and I am looking for something more elegant)

Answer (score 0):

use TexParams,like

```
Texture2D* tex = Director::getInstance()->getTextureCache()->addImage("CloseNormal.png");
Texture2D::TexParams param = {GL_LINEAR, GL_LINEAR, GL_REPEAT, GL_REPEAT};
tex->setTexParameters(param);
auto size = tex->getContentSize();
auto s = Sprite::createWithTexture(tex, Rect(0,0,size.width * 2, size.height * 2));
s->setPosition(Point(300,300));
this->addChild(s);
```

or like

```
auto s = Sprite::create("CloseSelected1.png");
auto size = s->getContentSize();
Texture2D::TexParams param = {GL_LINEAR, GL_LINEAR, GL_REPEAT, GL_REPEAT};
s->getTexture()->setTexParameters(param);
s->setTextureRect(Rect(0, 0, size.width * 2, size.height * 2));
s->setPosition(Point(200,200));
this->addChild(s);
```

Comment: Problem is that same sprite I have to change size/width in update loop,couple times in second, so this will work if I do not resize sprite ( in your case s)